# In my angular app, binding to value on an input shows the value but does not submit it and the ng-invalid class is still added

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to retrieve a username from my server and display it in an html input so the the user can see it and edit it if required. Then when they submit the form I will send it back to my server to update my database. The below code is currently how I'm trying to do this.
I am binding to the http input value with the accountUsername variable that gets its value from a http request. I do this inside AfterViewInit. The value is displayed inside the input but, if it is not changed, when the form is submitted, it sends `{username: ''}` and not the value.
Also the ng-invalid class is added even though there is a value.

Can someone help me out with the correct method to do this?

My app.component.ts file

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

  @ViewChild('accountForm') accountForm: NgForm
  accountUsername: string

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.http.get<{username: string}>(
      'http://localhost:80/accountinfo'
    ).subscribe({
      next: resData => {
        this.accountUsername = resData.username
      }
    })
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.accountForm.value)
  }
}
```

My app.component.html file

```
<form #accountForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label for="username">Username</label>
  <input 
    type="text" 
    id="username" 
    name="username" 
    [value]="accountUsername" 
    ngModel 
    #username="ngModel" 
    required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two-way binding with the banana-in-a-box `[()]` syntax:

```html
<form #accountForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="username" 
  name="username" 
  [(ngModel)]="accountUsername"
  required>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[Stackblitz here.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9tq4w3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)